# Symmetric matrix with 0 diagonal, each row (and column) being a permutation on $n-1$ symbols.

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $n$ denote a positive integer, and consider the set $S$ of $n\times n$ symmetric matrices with zero diagonal (denoted $A$) so that for each $j$, $a_{ij}$ ($i=1,2,\dots,n)$ is a permutation of $0,1,\dots,n-1$. What is $S$'s cardinality?

Some ideas: we may let the symmetric group $S_n$ act on $S$ by conjugating by the permutation matrices; we may replace $1,\dots,n-1$ with variables $x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}$ [or with some values, I had in mind the $n-1$th roots of unity] and try and find the eigenvalues of $A\in S$. Any idea will be appreciated, thanks.

(trivial observation: $n$ has to be even. indeed, assume $n=2m+1$. since $a_{ij}=a_{kl}\neq 0$ implies $i,k,j,l$ all different 
(assuming $\{i,j\}\neq \{k,l\}$), there are at most $2m$ elements in $A$ equal to $r$, for any $r=1,\dots,n-1$, even though there need to be $n$ such elements.)

Comment: Very interesting (and maybe hard?) question!  Where did it come from?  It is (I think) equivalent to an edge coloring problem: If you consider the row & column indices as node labels for an $n$-node complete graph, and each non-zero value in the matrix as a label for one of $n-1$ distinct colors, then each matrix is one distinct edge-coloring of that graph.  However, that does not make the problem easier IMHO...

Comment: Turns out someone asked a [very similar question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2511134/number-of-distinct-proper-minimal-edge-colorings-of-a-labeled-complete-graph), in the guise of no. of edge colorings.  I am not sure it's exactly the same.

Comment: @antkam that is a really nice observation! (it also makes the impossible case of odd $n$ easier to understand). I played around with matrices whose rows and columns are permutations of the indices, and naturally came to ask myself the above question.

Comment: Why do you want the diagonal to be zero?

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A036981](https://oeis.org/A036981). ([Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/3188d76fba7259a76eb6f09f52b5a0ad) I used to find it by enumerating the matrices up to $n=8$.)